# Azure AD B2C cannot connect to Azure AD identity provider

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I've got a SaaS solution that offers SSO with your work accounts or hosting and account registration using Azure AD B2C.

I've got a Azure AD app registration that is setup as a OIDC identity provider in B2C. I've been able to login via the work account successfully many times.

However, today I've been trying to setup some optional claims in the app registration and was having trouble getting those claims to show up, specifically the email claim. I tried to setup a claim map via Enterprise Applications > Single sign-on but this seems to have broken the link between AD and AD B2C. I'm now getting the following error message.

```
AADB2C90289: We encountered an error connecting to the identity provider. Please try again later. Correlation ID: 98764055-018d-4ff5-9c34-2cebfd5b9fae Timestamp: 2023-03-24 20:04:12Z
```

So far I've reverted the changes made via Enterprise Application, and regenerated the client secret but with no change.

Does anyone know what the issue with B2C talking to AD via the OIDC provider might be?

Comment: We have exactly the same error with federation that just started recently with no apparent cause. We have also mapped claims with Enterprise Applications > Single sign-on. We have filed a report with Microsoft. Will report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that worked for us is described [here](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/federation-error-between-azure-ad-and-azure-ad-b2c-e01876c5df62).

TLDR: Set this attribute to true in the manifest for the Enterprise Application

```
"acceptMappedClaims": true,
```

Comment: Thanks @rbrayb I'll check that out and see what it does. I ended up recreating the app registration to get it working but still would like to understand what happened.

Comment: I had a chance to test this and yes that is the magic attribute!