# Azure B2C setup user flow with MS Account returns AADB2C90289: We encountered an error connecting to the identity provider. Please try again later

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, idp

I want to add Microsoft Account (MSA) as an identity provider to Azure B2C.

I followed the steps in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-microsoft-account?pivots=b2c-user-flow and added MSA as user flow.

When I run the flow, I get to the screen where I grant access to my email address to the specified app, but then I'm forwarded to `<my redirect url>error=server_error&error_description=AADB2C90289:+We+encountered+an+error+connecting+to+the+identity+provider.+Please+try+again+later.Correlation+ID:[...]`

I re-created the app, and made sure the client id and client secret are correct, but I don't seem to get around this issue.

I also registered google as an identity provider and here the flow works without issues.

In the AD audit log I only see a generic error message.

I also tried the suggested fix from [Azure AD B2C cannot connect to Azure AD identity provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75838181/azure-ad-b2c-cannot-connect-to-azure-ad-identity-provider)

Answer (score 0):

I created an **Azure AD Application** and added redirect URI as `https://your-tenant-name.b2clogin.com/your-tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp`:

[image]

Now, I created **Azure AD B2C application** and added redirect URI as **`https://jwt.ms`** like below:

[image]

I created **Sign up and Sign in user flow and selected Identity provider** like below:

[image]

When I run the user flow, consent screen displayed like below:

[image]

ID token got generated successfully redirected to [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/) successfully like below:

[image]

Comment: I did the same thing: Create an AD app and afterwards an Azure B2C app, but still get the same error.

Comment: I re-created the setup and now it works. Thanks for your help!